# Problema ao abrir sub-relatório do IReports em outro terminal

Tags: java, relatório, ireport

Criei um relatório que busca informação em um sub-relatório para mostrar todas as informações.

Porém ao executar na máquina de desenvolvimento ele aparece o relatório sem nenhum problema tanto na IDE quanto executando o JAR gerado depois.

Mas ao executar o JAR em um outro computador o mesmo não carrega. Acusando que o sub-relatório não foi encontrado.

Encontrei em alguns fóruns soluções como alterar o caminho da busca do sub mas não obtive sucesso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Identifiquei que o parâmetro do relatório que buscava o sub-relatório informava o caminho do arquivo no meu computador como em outro terminal ele mudará o nome e caminho o sub não era encontrado.

No caso o sistema fica sempre instalado em um diretório igual pra todos inseri o sub-relatório em um local que sei que em todos os computadores existirá e mudei a configuração do relatório principal para buscar neste campo especifico.

O local onde mudei o caminho é em Propriedade do sub-relatório -> Subreport Expression -> neste campo indiquei o caminho absoluto.